# Is activation voltage the sum of voltage required to collapse depletion layer and band gap energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electricity, voltage, semiconductor-physics, light-emitting-diodes

Is the energy released when an electron moves from the valence to conductance band states the activation voltage or is activation voltage the energy required for electrons to overcome the depletion layer?

Comment: If you don't accept or vote answers to your questions, why do you think further questions will get answered? See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484024/207455

Comment: I would call neither of those an 'activation voltage'.